# Sign of $n$ th derivative of $f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, tetration, complex-dynamics

Let $f(z)$ satisfy $f(f(z)) = \operatorname{arcsinh}(z/2)$

More precisely, we construct such an $f(z)$ by using the fixpoint at $0$ and the related Koenigs function.

see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function

Now I wonder about the sign of the $n$ th derivative of $f(x)$ at point $x$ for real $x>0$.

Is there an easy way to compute the sign of $\frac{d^n}{d^n x} f(x)$ at point $x$ ?

Is there maybe a pattern ?

Such as at every fixed value $x>0$ there exists $p_x(x),m_x(x)$ such that $f(x) = p(x) + m(x)$

Where $p_x(x)$ is a real polynomial of $x$ (when expanded around $x$) and $m_x(x)$ is a smooth and completely monotonic function of $x$ at point $x$.

So in other words the tail of the taylor series expanded at some $x>0$ must be a smooth and completely monotonic function of $x$.

Notice the right-plane might not be analytic so the radius of taylor may differ.

Is this pattern true ?

And if not are there other patterns ?

What can we say about the signs of the taylor coefficients ??

I assume $\operatorname{arcsinh}(z/2)$ is a smooth and completely monotonic function for $x > 0$ but I am not sure.
The question depends on that.

( it is true that $\operatorname{arcsinh}(z/2)$ is a smooth and completely monotonic function at $x=0$ )

Maybe this fact helps :

A smooth ($C^{\infty}$) and completely monotonic function on an open interval( or semi-axis ) is always analytic on that interval( or semi-axis for the finite part ).

Comment: not heavily related but it reminded me of this open question at mathoverflow ( hope I can mention it here ? )  : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262444/interesting-stipulation-about-completely-monotone-functions

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether this is what you want. Getting the formal powerseries for $f(z)$ where $f(f(z))=\text{arcsinh}(z/2)$ gives me the first few coefficients as rational numbers scaled by powers of $r=\sqrt 2$:

```
        f(z)=                       0 
                                + 1/1 *z  / r
                                    0
                             -1/2.3^2 *z^3 / r^3 
                                    0
                     + 61/2^3.3^3.5^2 *z^5 / r^5 
                                    0
              -1.61.107/2^4.3^6.5^2.7 *z^7 / r^7 
                                    0
         + 23.573007/2^7.3^8.5^3.7.17 *z^9 / r^9 
                                    0
  -1.7.47.2495807/2^8.3^8.5^4.11^2.17 *z^11 / r^11
 ...
```

The rational values are approximations by Pari/GP "bestappr(coeff[j],20)" to $20$ dec digits.
Perhaps a pattern shows up which can then be confirmed by analyzing more of the (real-value) coefficients of $f(z)$.

*update* We can express the coefficients in polynomials with rational coefficients (and avoid the "bestappr()" q&d-approximations).
The signs of the coefficients seem to alternate (if this is what your are looking for - no proof so far). It should be easy to make strong heuristics up to 256 coefficients or so...

*update2* The first 128 coeffs, to be read from left to right and then downwards. The sign-pattern is obvious (computation in Pari/GP with 200 dec digits by default):

````
  0     0.707106781187  0    -0.0196418550330
  0   0.00199692192835  0  -0.000282633130071
  0   4.66246732419E-5  0   -8.40267581224E-6
  0   1.60405582097E-6  0   -3.18847526615E-7
  0   6.53062258310E-8  0   -1.36881540095E-8
  0   2.92204411215E-9  0  -6.33128110079E-10
  0  1.38883939032E-10  0  -3.07837972779E-11
  0  6.88400991538E-12  0  -1.55125867630E-12
  0  3.51904865918E-13  0  -8.03000824494E-14
  0  1.84190378622E-14  0  -4.24458478877E-15
  0  9.82234041987E-16  0  -2.28155176045E-16
  0  5.31777202161E-17  0  -1.24331651631E-17
  0  2.91522134549E-18  0  -6.85327943034E-19
  0  1.61500342282E-19  0  -3.81432433707E-20
  0  9.02735655755E-21  0  -2.14061912641E-21
  0  5.08507592149E-22  0  -1.20999527331E-22
  0  2.88371213542E-23  0  -6.88272148299E-24
  0  1.64501686210E-24  0  -3.93683762719E-25
  0  9.43321444962E-26  0  -2.26296404527E-26
  0  5.43468490285E-27  0  -1.30654683008E-27
  0  3.14417348980E-28  0  -7.57351773877E-29
  0  1.82590706348E-29  0  -4.40586526278E-30
  0  1.06399156745E-30  0  -2.57148297329E-31
  0  6.21946065308E-32  0  -1.50532915399E-32
  0  3.64591759787E-33  0  -8.83622185140E-34
  0  2.14288694933E-34  0  -5.19988786484E-35
  0  1.26252672336E-35  0  -3.06711075530E-36
  0  7.45506699743E-37  0  -1.81300202020E-37
  0  4.41124894050E-38  0  -1.07382550404E-38
  0  2.61521535521E-39  0  -6.37200189549E-40
  0  1.55321822968E-40  0  -3.78765992618E-41
  0  9.24028727559E-42  0  -2.25512346335E-42

```
````

Comment: This does not constitute an answer but it is nice. thanks !

Comment: If i am not mistaken the + - patterns breaks down before z^50. Although it might be in its tail again. Although i stated otherwise in the OP im starting to doubt. hmm A completely monotone function iterated gives completely monotone so that is why i suspected it holds at 0 ... ( that logic in reverse ) Oh yes i think it breaks down for expanded at z = 1. I got that confused I think. Sorry thinking out loud if you dont mind

Comment: @mick - please don't mind thinking loud. It helps to follow your intention!

Comment: thanks for the update, i agree. I think the probability rises with higher confirmation. because close to logs also forces the tails.

Comment: thanks again for the new update ! I dare to believe it now